# Error in PushNotification from iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I am trying to do a sample project on the Apple the push notification. I created an AppID, done some terminal commands, and finally got a Provisional Certificate for do the same.

I got the certificate installed on my device and SDK. Till now every thing goes fine. But when i try to run the app on the device.... it doesnt. It throws an error stating "Error from debugger:Error launching remote program:security policy error."

Can any one help me to overcome this.

Please Help needed.

thanks in advance
Shibin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced this problem before. Here is what solved the problem for me.

You should give it a try :

http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/iphone/how-to-get-rid-of-security-policy-error/

Comment: Hey frined got it.. i restarted my device. it works...

Thanks a lot.